# i doesnt do what i want it to doo .i am making a guess the num game

Tags: python-3.x

```
from random import *
name = input("what is your name:")

options = input('what difficulty do you want to play on [ easy , normal , hard ]:').lower

random_num = 0

if options == 'easy':
print('ok, you will get numbers between 0 - 7')
random_num = randint(0, 7)

elif options == 'normal':
    print('ok, you will get numbers between 0 - 10')
    random_num = randint(0, 10)

elif options == 'hard':
    print('ok, you will get numbers between 0 - 15')
    random_num = randint(0, 15)

else :
    print('sorry I am not able to understand please choose one from [ easy , normal , hard ]')

guess = input('ok i am ready guess a number in your range :')

if random_num == guess :
print('Yictory!!! , you won ,your guess was correct')

elif random_num == guess :
print('You lost!!! ,your guess was wrong')

else:
    print('unable to interpret')
```

can some one help me with this as it doesnt go to else at the end and it goes to the second elif
and i am a biggainer so plz help me as soon as possible . its python 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `guess` is a string when it comes from `input`; you'll need to cast it to an integer, as that's what `randint` gets you.

```
guess = int(input('ok i am ready guess a number in your range :'))
```

This will, of course, crash horribly if you input something that's not a number, but that's a different issue.

There are a number of other issues too, such as the  `if` and `elif` branches at the end being the same (i.e. you'd never get to "You lost"), and that you never *call* `.lower()`.

To add proper error handling (and let the player guess more than once), I'd maybe reformulate this as

```
from random import randint

name = input("what is your name:")

option_ranges = {
    "easy": 7,
    "normal": 10,
    "hard": 15,
}

while True:
    options = input("what difficulty do you want to play on [ easy , normal , hard ]:").lower()
    max_range = option_ranges.get(options)
    if max_range:  # found a correct option
        break
    print("sorry I am not able to understand please choose one from [ easy , normal , hard ]")

print(f"ok, you will get numbers between 0 - {max_range}")

random_num = randint(0, max_range)

while True:
    try:
        guess = int(input("ok i am ready guess a number in your range :"))
    except ValueError:
        print("unable to interpret")
        continue  # Go back to the loop
    if random_num == guess:
        print("Yictory!!! , you won ,your guess was correct")
        break
    print("You lost!!! ,your guess was wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is okay, except for the logic condition: This line

```
elif random_num == guess :
    print('You lost!!! ,your guess was wrong')
```

is the same as

```
if random_num == guess :
    print('Yictory!!! , you won ,your guess was correct')
```

Change the `elif` logic from `==` to not equal `!=`;

```
elif random_num != guess :
    print('You lost!!! ,your guess was wrong')
```

You should be good to go